# What is the correct way to make \newunit insert intersentence spaces?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

My university requires me to use the following bibliography style:

[image: University bibliography style example]

I am trying to achieve this by creating a custom `.bbx` file based on `standard.bbx`. The problem I am facing is that when I am using `\newunit` inside `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}`, biblatex inserts interword space between the year and the title:

[image: The incorrect result]

I would also like to use intersentence space between the author and the date. I am aware, though, that TeX always puts midword space after comma and what I want is not a standard behavior.

Here is the code which produces too small spaces:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%
  \printfield{year}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\addspace}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \finentry}
```

I have achieved an effect close to what I want by replacing it with the following:

```
\newbibmacro*{author+year+title}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \addcomma\enspace%
  \printfield{year}%
  \adddot\enspace%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{author+year+title}%
  \newblock%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\addspace}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \finentry}
```

[image: The result close to what I want to achieve]

The problem is, that in biblatex documentation adding spaces manually is discouraged. Moreover, using `\enspace` also seems like bad idea. If I am not mistaken, this will prevent TeX from adjusting width of the spaces when justifying text.

What would be the best practice to achieve the effect I want?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Maybr try replacing `\addspace` with `\quad` in the relevant portions of your code. You also can simply patch the bib macros/drivers, &c. using package `xpatch`.

Comment: Are you sure that this is really required? It might just be bad typesetting in the example. In theory you can tell `\newunit` to add more space with, say, `\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\quad}` (I chose `\quad` for a large effect, it may not be the exact space you need). But `\newunit`/`\newunitpunct` is used all over the place, so this might insert spaces where you don't want them. You can always say `\setunit{\addcomma\quad}%` instead of `\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%` if you want to change a particular space.

Comment: @moewe I am pretty sure that it _is_ bad typesetting. My university is pretty bad at formatting *sigh*. I just want my text to look as close to it as it is necessary. Still, the spaces between author, year and title are just too narrow for my taste.
I tried using `\setunit{\addcomma\quad}%` as you showed, but it still inserts narrow spaces as with `\newunit`.

Comment: Actually, your code did not work because I edited the wrong part of code. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me the large spaces in the screenshot look like bad typesetting (bad 'justification') rather than a conscious choice to use more space after commas. I would definitely not try and recreate this output in TeX.

Anyway, you can of course change the space produced by `\newunit`. `\newunit` just sends `\newunitpunct` to the punctuation buffer, so you can redefine `\newunitpunct`.
Its default definition from `biblatex.def` is

```
\newcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}
```

You can make that

```
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\quad}
```

or some such if you want more space.

It should be noted that `\newunit`/`\newunitpunct` is used all over the place and redefining it has the potential to change a lot.

`biblatex` has the option `block` to control the typesetting of bibliography blocks (introduced with `\newblock`). With `block=space,` you can introduce some additional space between blocks. Depending on your bibliography style and how it uses `\newblock` that might give some additional spacing in sensible locations.

For finer control some more work is needed. While most punctuation in `biblatex` is inserted with `\newunit` some (often modified) punctuation has its own commands that can easily be changed without affecting other punctuation.

Since you already seem to completely redefine the bibliography driver, you can of course just go for something like

```
\setunit{\addcomma\quad}%
```

instead of `\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%`.

Just remember that it is bad to have 'naked' `\add...`/`\space` commands in your driver and bibmacros. `\add...`/`\space` and friends should only appear within a `\setunit` or in a `\DeclareFieldFormat`.

Comment: The `block=space` option was exactly what I needed. Thank you!